# JQuery causing HTML to be format specific wrt closing tags?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.Net and, especially to JQuery. I've been trying to get my page to have JQuery tabs and, after a fashion, I have this working. However, it seems to me that the HTML in my aspx is now very sensitive to closing tags.

For example, it seems that this works (well, it doesn't cause errors)...

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

...but this doesn't work (ie. causes errors).

```
<head>
    <title/>
</head>
```

Are they (now) no longer equivalent ?

I noticed the same (but different errors) when I convert this...

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to...

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

What's the difference in the way that the tags are closed ?

Comment: What do you mean by the `title` tag 'not working'? Neithed of your examples have a value in them. As for why `script` tags cannot be self closing, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: using the first form, with a closing tag, my form works just fine. Using the second form, without a separate closing tag, the "tabs" javascript raises errors.

Comment: But `/head>` is wrong too. Now why don't you write valid HTML markup?

Answer (score 1):

Using `/>` at the end of the start tag instead of having an explicit end tag is an XML feature. For HTML, it only works in XHTML (which has to be real XHTML served with an `application/xhtml+xml` content type instead of a `text/html` content-type).

Comment: Oh... but what about tags like "<br/>" or "<p/>" ?

Comment: The end tag for `<br>` is forbidden. The `<p/>` is an error. (And an empty paragraph makes as much sense as an empty title, which is none at all).

Comment: There is an excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/1414562   :)